# jOOQ array field contains any of input list values condition

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Using postgresql, I have a table `product` and the array field of the `resticted_delivery_regions`:

```
ALTER TABLE "product"
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS "restricted_delivery_regions" CHARACTER VARYING(7)[];

COMMENT ON COLUMN "product"."restricted_delivery_regions"
    IS 'Prohibited regions for delivery, for example: {''US-NY'', ''US-NJ''}';
```

Using jOOQ on the code side, I'm trying to implement some specific condition like this (not compilant):

```
if (criteria.getRestrictedRegionsCount() > 0) {
    condition = condition.and(PRODUCT.RESTRICTED_DELIVERY_REGIONS.notContainsAnyOf(criteria.getRestrictedRegionsList()));
}
```

Where:

1. `PRODUCT.RESTRICTED_DELIVERY_REGIONS` -- is autogenerated `TableField<ProductRecord, String[]>`, telling us the product's delivery resticted regions
2. `criteria.getRestrictedRegionsList()` -- input of prohibited for delivery regions, by which products should be filtered

Questions are:

1. Is it possible to code such a query using jOOQ means?
2. If not, what is the best way to implement such a condition construct?

P.S.
`Field::notContains()` is not an option here, because it looks for a match over the entire input array, not individual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, that's just the `&&` operator. jOOQ doesn't support it natively, but as always, you can easily add support yourself using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
condition.and("not ({0} && {1})", 
    PRODUCT.RESTRICTED_DELIVERY_REGIONS,

    // Pass the bind value using the DataType of the generated column,
    // for convenience
    val(criteria.getRestrictedRegionsList(), PRODUCT.RESTRICTED_DELIVERY_REGIONS)
);
```

This is assuming your list is already an array. If it isn't you'll have to convert it to an array, first.

As [everything you do with jOOQ is effectively dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), you can create a small library for such vendor-specific functions, e.g.

```java
public static <T> Condition containsAny(
    Field<T[]> left,
    T... right
) {
    return containsAny(left, val(right, left));
}

public static <T> Condition containsAny(
    Field<T[]> left,
    Field<T[]> right
) {
    return DSL.condition("({0} && {1})", left, right);
}
```